# How to set focus to Textview in HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android

I have a dynamic array of **Textview** in HorizontalScrollView.
Now i want to set focus to particular **Textview**

How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this Code for Focus

```
 textview[i].requestFocus();
```